# Split a column into two columns based on filter value in query

Tags: sql, voltdb

Is it possible to split a column into the two columns when executing query based on filter value.

For example, given database schema

```
x varchar
a integer
b 0,1
```

I can execute a query

```
select x , sum(a) as asum from t group by x
```

That will end up with

```
 x | asum 
---+-----
...| ...
```

Now I want to calc distinct sum for a if b is equal to 0 and 1

So the result set should be

```
 x | as for x = 0 | as for x = 1
---+--------------+---------------
...|    ...       |  ...
```

Of cause I can execute

```
select x , sum(a) as asum, b as as from t group by x, b
```

But that will require additional application side transformation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most databases, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select x,
       sum(case when b = 0 then a else 0 end) as a_0,
       sum(case when b = 1 then a else 0 end) as a_1
from t
group by x;
```

Voltdb appears to support `case` ([here](https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/sqlref_select.php)), so this should work.